# How do I overcome "Ole::Storage::FormatError: OLE2 signature is invalid" error when re-saving the doc is not an option?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spreadsheet, xls, ole

I’m using Rails 4.2.7 and just added the spreadsheet gem to my Gemfile

```
gem 'spreadsheet'
```

Sadly, when I execute this call against a file that ends in “.xls”

```
    book = Spreadsheet.open file_location
```

I get the below error.  Unfortunately, it is not an option to resave this document in another Excel format (I don’t even have Excel installed on my computer).  How can I parse this xls file?  I’m open to using another gem if it solves the problem.

```
Ole::Storage::FormatError: OLE2 signature is invalid
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/ruby-ole-1.2.12/lib/ole/storage/base.rb:378:in `validate!'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/ruby-ole-1.2.12/lib/ole/storage/base.rb:370:in `initialize'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/ruby-ole-1.2.12/lib/ole/storage/base.rb:112:in `new'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/ruby-ole-1.2.12/lib/ole/storage/base.rb:112:in `load'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/ruby-ole-1.2.12/lib/ole/storage/base.rb:79:in `initialize'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/ruby-ole-1.2.12/lib/ole/storage/base.rb:85:in `new'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/ruby-ole-1.2.12/lib/ole/storage/base.rb:85:in `open'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spreadsheet-1.1.4/lib/spreadsheet/excel/reader.rb:1282:in `setup'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spreadsheet-1.1.4/lib/spreadsheet/excel/reader.rb:140:in `read'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spreadsheet-1.1.4/lib/spreadsheet/excel/workbook.rb:32:in `open'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spreadsheet-1.1.4/lib/spreadsheet.rb:67:in `open'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spreadsheet-1.1.4/lib/spreadsheet.rb:73:in `open'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/xls_to_my_object_times_converter_service.rb:12:in `get_my_object_times'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/xls_processor_service.rb:15:in `process_page_data'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/abstract_import_service.rb:82:in `process_my_object_data'
    from (irb):3
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some problems with spreadsheet when I tried it.  That was some time ago, so I don't recall exactly what happened but I believe it was a similar OLE error.  It has been updated since then, as well.  But, since you mentioned you would consider another gem, I switched to [roo](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo) and it has worked quite well for me.  One very strong benefit is that it can handle many different formats, not just Excel-compatible.

Comment: That is true for legacy files, as specified in the documentation.  "Excel 97, Excel 2002 XML, and Excel 2003 XML formats when using the roo-xls gem (xls, xml)".  Also, "Google spreadsheets with read/write access when using roo-google"

Comment: K, so the link in your answer is NOT what would address the error I saw and I should use roo-xls instead?

Comment: @Dave, not at all.  You want roo.  The others are for special edge cases. The gemspec for each requires roo, so they are a package, but generally you want roo.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong but when I include "roo" in my Gemfile, I get the error "ArgumentError: Can't detect the type of /tmp/file1481730610095.xls - please use the :extension option to declare its type." when parsing my .xls file.  AFter replacing "roo" with "roo-xls," I don't see this error anymore.

Comment: @Dave That indicates that your original OLE2 error was due to some problem with the actual file.  Well, what can you tell me about that file?  Is it circa 2003 or earlier?  What software created or updated it?  roo-xls is appropriate in the cases I mentioned above but, again, those are edge cases and really should almost not occur in the real world today  I'll take a look at your code if you post it.  But, if it works with roo-xls, I guess that is okay?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Dave I know you said you don't have Excel installed.  But, if you could find some way to open it with Excel, and perhaps save it into a new file, that could certainly help diagnose the problem.

Comment: YOu led me down the right path here, so I'm accepting, but know that roo did not solve the problem I was having above -- it was roo-xls that healed the pain.

Comment: @Dave  Glad I could help.  Must be a very old file or some formatting error within it.  Anything current and healthy should be handled by roo alone.